# web pages using javascript cant work if user's browser has javascript disable...so is there any way to run command like onclick without javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

plz anyone help me give me solution to run command like onclick without javascript....thanks
//javascript code:

```
                function selectedproperty(id)
                {
                document.getElementById("pid").value=id;
                document.getElementById("form1").submit();
                }

                function singleproperty(id)
                {
                document.getElementById("pid").value=id;
                document.getElementById('form1').action="singlepropertydetail.php"
                document.getElementById("form1").submit();
                }  

// html/php code 

 <ul>
    <?PHP
    $sql=mysql_query("select build_name,flat_no,property_id from new_property where owner='".$ownerid."'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql))
    {
    echo "<li onclick='singleproperty(".$row[2].");' >".$row[0]." ".$row[1]."</li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: well onclick is a event that fires a javascript code, there is no way you can do this. Instead you can check if javascript is disabled. If disabled you can redirect user to no javascript page.

Comment: You should alert the user to enable java script. `<noscript><p>Please enable JavaScript in your browser for better use of the website.</p></noscript>`

Comment: thanks for reply..okkk...so is there any way to enable browser's javascript using code????

Comment: many sites warn people with js disable of reduced usability.

Comment: major security risk if that was possible.

Comment: @ashishkansara: no you can't enable java script by code it should be enable by user.

Comment: yes i did <noscript> in my page but still i want to sent value retrived from database to other page..

Comment: if i sent using <a> then next pahe i have to retrive using GET method but it shows in url....so any solution for that to hide data in url??

Comment: @ashishkansara: go through this link http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/target_url_hiding.php

Answer (score 1):

You put a form with a button inside the li. The user clicks on the button and if js is disabled it posts back to the server and it does the logic presenting the user with the required modification to the page. You JavaScript to prevent the form from submitting and handle the logic client side if js is enabled.

Here is an idea of how it would look

```
<li onclick='singleproperty(".$row[2].");' >
    <form method='post' onsubmit='return false'>
        <input name='singleproperty' type='hidden' value='".$row[2]."'>
        <input type='submit' value='".$row[0]." ".$row[1]."'>
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

To Pass the values to the server you can do either of the below

1. Use a submit button which will submit the form to the server. This will hide the parameters from the URL and would use request body.
2. If your page is just doing read operation it is safe to perform GET request on the page where the parameters will be present in the URL.

If you want to write an app which should work in the absence of JavaScript you must use design principles such as [Graceful degradation & Progressive enhancement](http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/). Explaining in detail on how to achieve this will be outside the scope of this Question & Answer site.

Or, you can have a separate HTML only site as GMail does.

The decision of whether to support JavaScript less browser or have a separate site or do graceful degradation has to be thought through before the application is written and corresponding compromises has to be made well in advance.